# Sabre Unable to use "Revalidate Itinerary" REST API

Tags: rest, sabre

I am trying to follow the developer guide for a air booking process found in the documentation. https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/workflows/air-booking

Here, I have used token based authentication (v2) and I could successfully search and book using the rest api. However, Upon hitting the **revalidate itinerary** api with the example found in the documentation https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/revalidate_itinerary/reference-documentation

Here, I am getting following error. (Note: I have changed the pcc code in here. The original request uses the correct pnr.)

Response:

```json
{
    "groupedItineraryResponse": {
        "version": "6.3.0",
        "messages": [
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "WORKERTHREAD",
                "code": "TRANSACTIONID",
                "text": "3019835637227710880"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "SERVER",
                "code": "ASE032LPSCIL668.ATSE.CERT.ASCINT.SABRECIRRUS.COM",
                "text": "27038"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "DRE",
                "code": "RULEID",
                "text": "25961"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "DEFAULT",
                "code": "RULEID",
                "text": "25959"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "IF2",
                "code": "PROCESS",
                "text": "PCC EPCC: Revalidate Itinerary not requested."
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "ERR",
                "code": "ERR",
                "text": "Error during Processing"
            }
        ],
        "statistics": {
            "itineraryCount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

API URL: https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v3/shop/flights/revalidate

Request json:

```json
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "RPH": "0",
                "DepartureDateTime": "2021-08-14T00:00:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "KRK"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "WAW"
                }
            }
        ],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "PseudoCityCode": "EPCC",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "TN"
                        },
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "200ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "DataSources": {
                    "NDC": "Disable",
                    "ATPCO": "Enable",
                    "LCC": "Disable"
                },
                "NumTrips": {}
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "SeatsRequested": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "Version": "3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to list all the flights with booking classes in `TPA_Extension` under `OriginDestinationInformation`.

So, your `OriginDestinationInformation` should look something like this:

```
      "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "RPH": "0",
                "DepartureDateTime": "2021-10-11T14:50:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "BEG"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                },
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "SegmentType": {
                        "Code": "O"
                    },
                    "Flight": [
                        {
                            "Number": 1417,
                            "DepartureDateTime": "2021-10-11T14:50:00",
                            "ArrivalDateTime": "2021-10-11T16:40:00",
                            "Type": "A",
                            "ClassOfService": "K",
                            "OriginLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "BEG"
                            },
                            "DestinationLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                            },
                            "Airline": {
                                "Operating": "LX",
                                "Marketing": "LX"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
```