# Sabre API - Revalidate Itinerary Gives Error

Tags: sabre

I'm new to the Sabre suite of API's and I'm currently playing around with them. I am able to get results of flights for `Bargain Finder Max`, however for `Revalidate Itinerary` I get an error.

Here is my request:

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2023-06-21T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "ZYL"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LHR"
        },
        "RPH": "0"
      },
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2023-07-22T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LHR"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "ZYL"
        },
        "RPH": "1"
      }
    ],
    "POS": {
      "Source": [
        {
          "PseudoCityCode": "F9CE",
          "RequestorID": {
            "CompanyName": {
              "Code": "TN"
            },
            "ID": "1",
            "Type": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
      "IntelliSellTransaction": {
        "RequestType": {
          "Name": "200ITINS"
        }
      }
    },
    "TravelPreferences": {
      "TPA_Extensions": {
        "DataSources": {
          "ATPCO": "Enable",
          "LCC": "Disable"
        },
        "NumTrips": {}
      }
    },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
      "AirTravelerAvail": [
        {
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
            {
              "Code": "ADT",
              "Quantity": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "SeatsRequested": [
        1
      ]
    },
    "Version": "3"
  }
}
```

And here is my response:

```
{
  "groupedItineraryResponse": {
    "version": "6.7.1",
    "messages": [
      {
        "severity": "Info",
        "type": "SERVER",
        "code": "GCA14-ISELL-TN-00-2023-04-01-HHCL",
        "text": "27131"
      },
      {
        "severity": "Info",
        "type": "WORKERTHREAD",
        "code": "TRANSACTIONID",
        "text": "7225615068441469456"
      },
      {
        "severity": "Info",
        "type": "DRE",
        "code": "RULEID",
        "text": "25961"
      },
      {
        "severity": "Info",
        "type": "DEFAULT",
        "code": "RULEID",
        "text": "25959"
      },
      {
        "severity": "Error",
        "type": "WPNI",
        "code": "WPNI.ITIN",
        "shortCode": "WPNI:101",
        "text": "Itinerary missing from Revalidate request."
      },
      {
        "severity": "Error",
        "type": "ERR",
        "code": "ERR",
        "text": "Error during Processing"
      }
    ],
    "statistics": {
      "itineraryCount": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I'm obviously not supplying the correct request parameters hence I get this error: `"Itinerary missing from Revalidate request."`

Can someone guide me on what parameters I should supply please.

Many thanks.

On another note, I also face issues with `Create Passenger Name Record` with the error `"Authorization failed due to no access privileges"`, any guidance here will be appreciated too.

I went through the documentation but couldn't achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details about the itinerary (segments).

`OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.OriginDestinationInformation.TPA_Extensions.Flight` is missing.

[image: screenshot example]

Similar question: [Sabre Unable to use "Revalidate Itinerary" REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393026/sabre-unable-to-use-revalidate-itinerary-rest-api)

---

The endpoint "Create Passenger Name Record" is not available in testing environment (response from Sabre Support).